# Vertical scrolling of the text inside DIV (in a loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

I need to have a div with a text inside it, that will scroll from top to bottom in a loop.

Actually I found what I need here:    **[Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjmYNa)**

But the problem is that I'm using CSS3 in the example and the scrolling is not working below IE10 browsers, since CSS3 us not supported there.

Is there some solution for getting the same result as the example above? Maybe by using plugin, managing `margins via JS`, etc?

Comment: Will have to use javascript to change the margin-top in a set of intervals

Answer (score 0):

This might not be conventional but you can try the `<marquee>` tag

it works both in IE and FF, and the last time I checked, safari too.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" height="250" 
   scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="10"">
  Your content goes here
</marquee>
```

should give you what you want,
and you can style them like any `<div>`...
and then there is the added advantage of having no javascript...

It gets better, try this in any browser

```
onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()"
```

And this in IE

```
style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha( Opacity=0,
FinishOpacity=100, 
Style=1, StartX=0,  FinishX=0, StartY=0, FinishY=10) 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha( Opacity=100, FinishOpacity=0, 
Style=1, StartX=0, FinishX=0, StartY=90, FinishY=100)"
```

As attributes of the marquee tag...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

JS fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/0pfwkw03/2/

```
function run(){
var top = parseInt($(".inner").css("top").replace("px",""));
var height = $(".outer").outerHeight();
if(top <  height)
{
   $(".inner").animate({"top":height},5000,run)           
}
else
{
    $(".inner").css({"top":-height});
    run();
}

}
run();
```